# How to store vars in context. Cucumber, groovy

Tags: java, tdd, cucumber-jvm

I want to save several variables for 1 scenario like have a scope for several steps.
For example, if I have login action and do it by rest API. 
I get a response and some cookie value like a session id.
For all other requests, I must use this value.

If I need it for one steps group it's okay to store the value in the steps class, but It doesn't work if I want to reuse other steps.

I read about conception World but didn't find any doc about it realization for java cucumber.

Have someone decision for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where cucumber-spring comes to the rescue. You can create A `State` class, mark it with `@Component` and inject in any StepDefs classes.
So the `State` class will contain shared state that may be used in any scenario.